# Using Get-WinEvent to parse stored evtx files by error level

Tags: powershell, event-viewer

I am trying to parse locally stored saved extx files from other 2008 servers using Powershell.  My first goal is to parse by "Error" level.  I used the following PS command:

Get-WinEvent -Path C:\Logs\logfile.evtx | Where-Object {$_.LevelDisplayName -eq 'Error'}

However, I only get back a fraction of the "errors' from the event logs.  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?  I've also tried the -FilterHashtable flag, although I think that would only work on my own logs, correct?  Thanks.

Comment: why you don't get error from event log  `Get-EventLog * | foreach { get-eventlog $_.log -EntryType Error }`  ? you can pipe and get more information

Answer (score 0):

put your command in array

```
$a= @(Get-WinEvent -Path C:\Logs\logfile.evtx)
```

then get

```
$a[0..25] | where { $_.leveldisplayname -match "Error" }
```

i suppose you have 25 event log in your file